# Git reset --hard did not remove files from pull?

Tags: git

I am new to git and pretty confused by this.

I accidentally pulled the wrong branch into the branch I was working on, so I searched and found `git reset --hard` is meant to pull it back to the original state. I did this, but nothing happened - the files I pulled remain.

I then used `git reflog show` to see if I could do something like `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` but none of the repos listed are the one I am working on.

Would anyone be able to help me just reverse this accidental pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset your branch to branch `master` instead of `wrong-branch`.

**Note that this will blow away any changes you had on branch `master` that you did not push to the remote.**

```
# fetch from remote to make sure you have all latest changes
git fetch origin
# reset to the correct branch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the hash of commit that you want to restor something like

```
git reset --hard  [<commit>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have merged the origin/wrong-branch to your local branch(e.g br), so the head is changed.

If you didn't change anything in local branch, you can just reset to origin/br

```
git reset --hard origin/br
```

or you need to find the commit hash before you pull, and then reset to it

```
git reset --hard <commitHash>
```